# C# test private static method of public static class

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I'm a little confused about how to perform these test. I know about the existence of `PrivateObject` to test private class and `PrivateType` to test private static class, but how can I test a private static method of a PUBLIC static class?

```
public static class Clients {
    // CUT
    private static List<string> GenerateAddresses(string AppPath) {
        // CUT
    }
}
```

In my unit test class I tried

```
PrivateType testClients = new PrivateType(Clients);
```

but I get the error

> 'Clients' is a type, which is not valid in the given context

The error is a bit confusing and google bring me to completly different problems. Am I using 'Clients' wrong with `PrivateType`? Or should I test in a different way given that `Clients` is public?

Comment: `new PrivateType(typeof(Clients))` ?  (Side note: Should you even be directly testing private members at all?  That creates a lot of coupling through the interface of the object and into its implementation, which should be of no concern to the tests.)

Comment: The constructor requires an instance of `System.Type`, not a Type name: `new PrivateType(typeof(Clients))`

Comment: Show us the constructor of PrivateType. What does it expect? What you have currently doesn't makes much sense which is exactly what the compiler is telling you

Comment: @bashrc https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms243359.aspx

Comment: Thank you @David and Dennis_E , it seems obvious... now :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Or should I test in a different way given that `Clients` is public?

Yes: `Clients` is the unit you're testing.  If it's not exposing `GenerateAddresses` publicly, it's not part of its surface API, and in theory is just there to support the internals of the class.

In unit testing, test the observable behaviour of the class - don't worry about how it goes about doing it internally.

Comment: Ok but thile developing I need to test the (quite long) code executed by `GenerateAddresses` private method. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Unit tests can hint at design smell. If it's something you want to test, it should likely be public. If you're doing too much work in your private method, consider splitting your private parts into a new class which would have testable public interfaces of its own. Then use this new class instead of a private method.

Comment: Are you sure you need to test it directly?  If it's `private`, it's there for the use of other members of the class (ie test those).  It may change, or be deleted altogether as far as consumers of the class (and your tests) are concerned.

Comment: @JamesThorpe ok I start to get it... In fact I can test the public method that actually use this private method. I will need to do it later anyway... Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

`var testClients = new PrivateType(typeof(Clients));`

`PrivateType` expects a [Type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1) object rather than the symbol name.

But I would rather suggest re-thinking your test strategy. Testing private methods is usually not required. If you find that you are not able to get a decent code coverage from the public methods you may be in need for some refactoring.